# is using this technique for android request/response safe?

Tags: android, rest, httprequest

I was just wondering if this is a good way to communicate in android or is there a safer and better way?

```
  btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            //Create the request
            **String url** = "http://10.0.2.2:80/practice/mysql_demo/inserting.php?";
            url = url + "txtName=" + txtName.getText().toString() + "&";
            url = url + "txtAge=" + txtAge.getText().toString() + "&";
            url = url + "txtAddress=" + txtAddress.getText().toString() + "&";
            url = url + "txtContact=" + txtContact.getText().toString() + "&";
            url = url + "txtOtherInformation=" + txtOtherInformation.getText().toString();

            **executeQuery(url)**;
            selectRecords(lstStudents);
        }
});
**public void executeQuery(String url)**
{
    //execute the URL, and get the result
    try
    {
        HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet http_get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse http_response = http.execute(http_get);
        HttpEntity http_entity = http_response.getEntity();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(http_entity.getContent()));
        String result = br.readLine();

        Toast.makeText(PHPDemo.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(PHPDemo.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a `thread` or `Asynctask` for network related operation.

```
 HttpResponse http_response = http.execute(http_get);
```

Post Honeycomb you will get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Use `AsyncTask` or use a thread`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

For Asynctask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Note: You cannot update ui from the background thread. You can update ui on the ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

@Raghunandan is right. In addition to that, I recommend to URL-encode the query parameter names and values individually. You can use `URLEncoder.encode` with `"UTF-8"` as the encoding.

Since you asked if there is a better way:

You might want to consider [HttpUrlConnection over Apache's HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633236/apache-httpclient-4-x-vs-httpurlconnection-which-one-is-faster-on-android) for newer Android releases.

You might also want to check out some [Android networking libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902716/comparison-of-android-networking-libraries-okhttp-retrofit-volley), like Volley or OkHttp, etc.